# F# ASP.NET Core Minimal Web API - Why does the generated endpoint ignore parameter names when not supplied a lambda?

Tags: asp.net-core, lambda, reflection, f#

I created a .NET core web API from the standard F# template and added these lines:

```
let add x y = x + y

app.MapGet("addUgly", new Func<_,_,_>(add))

app.MapGet("addPretty", new Func<_,_,_>(fun x y -> add x y))
```

When I access the `addPretty` endpoint, I can supply parameters with the desired names:
`https://localhost:7129/addPretty?x=1&y=2`

However, in order to access the `addUgly` endpoint, I must supply these parameters:
`https://localhost:7129/addUgly?delegateArg0=3&delegateArg1=4`

**Is there a way to have the generated endpoint use the desired parameter names without using a lambda?** (or other constructs that involve unnecessary boilerplate, like creating a controller)?

I checked whether `add` and `(fun x y -> add x y)` had differently structured type definitions, but they both have `Invoke` methods with parameters named `x` and `y`, so I don't know why those names get lost in one case but not the other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way to have the generated endpoint use the desired parameter names without using a lambda?

I think the answer is No for now. This appears to an open issue in the F# compiler. See language suggestion: [Use same parameters names when constructing a delegate from a function](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/1145).

Comment: Good observation